# WebClient AsyncCompleted event for multiple files combined

Tags: vb.net, events, webclient

I have a windows form through which a user can select multiple files they want to download. Once the files are downloaded they are processed further. I am using the `AsyncCompletedEventArgs` event to track progress of each download.

Each of the selected files gets downloaded using the function below :

```vb
Public Function DownloadFileOnline(FileName As String)
    Try
        fileReader = New WebClient()
        Dim Address As String
                
        Address = getURL(FileName)
        If (Not System.IO.Directory.Exists(Globals.LocalPath)) Then
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Globals.LocalPath)
        End If
        If Not (System.IO.File.Exists(Globals.LocalPath + FileName)) Then
            AddHandler fileReader.DownloadFileCompleted, AddressOf download_complete
            AddHandler fileReader.DownloadProgressChanged, AddressOf Download_ProgressChanged
            fileReader.QueryString.Add("fileName", FileName)
            fileReader.DownloadFileAsync(New Uri(Address), Globals.LocalPath + FileName)
        End If
    Catch ex As HttpListenerException
        CSMessageBox.ShowError("Error accessing the Library", ex)
        LogHelper.WriteLog("Error accessing the Library" + ex.Message, LogHelper.LogLevels.Error)
    Catch ex As Exception
        CSMessageBox.ShowError("Error accessing the Library", ex)
        LogHelper.WriteLog("Error accessing the Library" + ex.Message, LogHelper.LogLevels.Error)
    End Try
End Function
```

I am able to get the download completed event for each of the files individually using the function below:

```vb
Private Sub download_complete(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As AsyncCompletedEventArgs)
    RaiseEvent DownloadDone(sender, e)
    RemoveHandler fileReader.DownloadFileCompleted, AddressOf download_complete
    RemoveHandler fileReader.DownloadProgressChanged, AddressOf Download_ProgressChanged
End Sub
```

Once all the files are downloaded I plan to execute a function on all of them together. Is there a way I can raise an event when all of the selected files are finished downloading?

Comment: You're asking the wrong question. Of course there's a way to raise an event when all files have downloaded. You already know how to raise an event because you're already doing it in that code. That's how you raise an event when all files have downloaded. The actual question you want answered is how can you know when all files have downloaded. That's what you need to actually think about. If this was a manual process, how would you do then? That's exactly how you do it in code. The possible answers to that should be obvious because we all do that sort of thing all the time.

Comment: Thank you for your response @jmcilhinney, right now I am thinking to keep a track of how many files have been requested by the user and then check how many downloadcomplete events I have received. Once these two numbers match, I can trigger the rest of the process.

Comment: That sounds like a reasonable option but you'd need two variables for that, i.e. one for the total number of files to be downloaded and one for the number currently downloaded. You can do it with just one variable if you set it to the total number of files at the outset and then decrement it each time a download completes. Once that variable hits zero, you know you're done.

Comment: Sounds good. I will try that. Thank you :)